# Git selective commit

Tags: git, eclipse

I am using eGit plugin with eclipse.

I have made changes to 7 files locally and then figured out no changes needed for one of the files - so I have to only commit 6 files and revert the changes on the 7th file.

How can I accomplish this using eGit?

It appears to be that using eGit, I can either commit all or reset all. But I want to only commit selective files and revert the changes on other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, right-click the file you wish to revert, hover over "Replace With..." and select "Latest from HEAD". Then commit everything else as you would normally.